# How to rename multiple files in a folder that follow a specific name pattern

Tags: python, file-rename

I have multiple files in a folder that are named following this pattern 'AF-A0A0A0MRZ7-F1-model_v4.pdb', 'AF-Q1GBF7-F1-model_v4.pdb', 'AF-X5IWT5-F1-model_v4.pdb' and I would like to rename them for just 'AA0A0A0MRZ7.pdb', 'Q1GBF7.pdb', 'X5IWT5.pdb'.

I tried the script bellow, but it only renamed a few files in the folder.

```
import os
import shutil

directory = (r'\\...')

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
  
    if filename.startswith('AF-') and filename.endswith('-F1-model_v4.pdb'):
        try:
            parts = filename.split('-')
            
            new_filename = parts[1]+'.pdb'
            
            old_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            new_path = os.path.join(directory, new_filename)
            
            shutil.move(old_path, new_path)
        except Exception as e:
            # Print the error message if an error occurs
            print(f'Error renaming file {filename}: {e}')
```

Comment: I tried it on my computer and it worked for both filenames you mentioned. Perhaps it has to do with the directory?

Comment: Just a guess but it could be a case sensitivity issue? maybe you have some `.PDB` file you think are `.pdb`.

Comment: try printing every `old_path` and `new_path` and see if they are all correct.

Comment: Make sure the comparison parts to extract required patterns correctly working or not...Like print them once before rename...I'm pretty sure it's nothing wrong with file rename part...

Answer (score 1):

I think you're almost done, did you already tried the `os.rename()` function instead of `shutil.move()`?

```py
os.rename(old_path, new_path)
```

Comment: I just tried. I did not change anything, but thank you for your suggestion.